# How to get image from url website in imageview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

I am trying to get image in ImageView from url website but the image not show so,
What is the wrong in this code?
This is the url of the [image](http://test-dashboard1.seeloz.com/system/images/products_images/86/5454544114_1401886223?1401886223).

It is my Main Activity

```
ImageView i;
private Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    i=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);




    bitmap=GetBitmapfromUrl("http://test-dashboard1.seeloz.com/system/images/products_images/86/5454544114_1401886223?1401886223");
    i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


}


public Bitmap GetBitmapfromUrl(String scr) {
    try {
        URL url=new URL(scr);
        HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input=connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return bmp;



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
}}
```

in the XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="179dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.image"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.image.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What  is result of GetBitmapfromUrl function?

Comment: You should post your logcat with errors and stack traces. You will probably have a NetworkOnMainThreadExceptio. You have to put your code in an AsyncTask or thread. Moreover internet permission in manifest.

Comment: Could you clarify the question?

Comment: Also, I can't really see an image from the url you provided. Is the url correct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Doing network IO in the main thread is evil. Better to avoid.

Also - your url resource access is wrong.

Use something like this instead:

```
 private Bitmap bmp;

   new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {                  
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                InputStream in = new URL(IMAGE_URL).openStream();
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
               // log error
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (bmp != null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }

   }.execute();
```

This is the 'old way' of loading url resources into display. Frankly speaking, I have not written such code in a *long* time. [Volley](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library) and [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) simply do it much better
than me, including transparent local cache, multiple loader-threads management and 
enabling effective resize-before-load policies. All but coffee :)

Answer (score 7):

Give it a try with [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). It should take you almost one full line of code and less than a minute to set it up.

In your case, that would be:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(""http://imageurlgoeshere").into(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be loading multiple images from URL's in your app, it's definitely worth looking into:

[**nostra13's "Universal Image Loader"**](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

It's an awesome library with tons of features to display images from URLs, cast to bitmaps, etc.

Once you've included the class and declared the imageloader + imageloader configuration, its a simple as this:

```
imageLoader.displayImage("http://www.yoursite.com/my_picture.png", imageView);
```

Where imageView is the imageView you would like the image to appear in.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in code but with the server. Try this sample url and tell me if is it working:

http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png