# Drawable not displaying in ImageView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Hello I am running into a silly error and I think I might be missing something. I currently have a list of objects. The objects have a title, description and an image. The title and description display properly, but for some reason the Image won't. I added the objects on another activity and made a list, when the user selects the item they wanted to see it send the id to this new page where it pulls the object. I added a random image as jpg to the application to see if it pulse and it does, but it looks a little weird. Any ideas why the images won't be pulling from the list? Thank you in advance.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:src="@drawable/img"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="News Title"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/desc"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
CustomOBJ selOBJ = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.det);
    Bundle objID = getIntent().getExtras();
    for(int x = 0; x < MainActivity.listobjs.size(); x++){
        if (MainActivity.listobjs.get(x).getID().equals(objID.getString("object") )){
            selOBJ = MainActivity.listobjs.get(x);
            break;
        }
    }

    TextView Title =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.desc);
    ImageView objPic=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);

    Title.setText(selOBJ.getName());
    description.setText(selOBJ.getDescription());
    objPic.setImageDrawable(selOBJ.getObjPic());

}
```

CustomOBJ Class:

```
public class CustomOBJ {
private String objID;
private String name;
private String Description;
private Drawable objPic;

public CustomOBJ(String i, String n, String d, Drawable pic) {
    objID = i;
    name = n;
    Description = d;
    objPic = pic;
}

public String getID() { return objID; }
public String getName() {return name;}
public String getDescription() {return description;}
public Drawable getObjPic() {return objPic; }
```

}

MainActivity:

```
public void jsonTolist(){
    //parse json data
    try{
        jArray = new JSONArray(welcome.result);
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.i("log_tag", "title:" + json_data.getString("title")

            );



            if(listobjs.isEmpty() || isNewsName(listobjs,json_data) == false){
                Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations(json_data.getString("img"));

                selOBJ = new CustomOBJ(json_data.getString("id"), json_data.getString("title"), json_data.getString("desc"), drawable);
                listobjs.add(selOBJ);
            }


        }
    }catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Load Images:

```
private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url){
    try{
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exc="+e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your CustomOBJ class?

Comment: please could you post CustomOBJ class code, to see what is happening here: objPic.setImageDrawable(selOBJ.getObjPic());

Comment: Thank you for your help! I re edited my code and added the customOBJ class

Comment: there is no use for that 'for loop'. directly pass that 'x' value from 1st activity through bundle and get image drawable from your list using 'x' from 2nd activity

Comment: @Lingeshwaran, I am using Bundle objID = new Bundle(); to insert the ID in here, can I use this to insert the customOBJ as well?

Comment: @paul590 there is no valid constructor in CustomOBJ class.

Comment: @LingesShwaran thank you I missed that I updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sender Side:**

```
Bundle d1 = new Bundle();
d1.putInt("d",0);
```

**Receiver Side:**

```
Bundle objID = getIntent().getExtras();
int x = objID .getInt("d");     

if (MainActivity.listobjs.get(x).getID()
.equals(objID.getString("object") ))
{
        selOBJ = MainActivity.listobjs.get(x);
    }
```

Before doing this kindly check CustomOBJ class have a valid constructor or not.

ref this link also

[How to get image from url website in imageview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535924/how-to-get-image-from-url-website-in-imageview-in-android)

Comment: Hello Lingeshwaran, Thank you for providing me with this information. I had a question about the image link you provided me with, is there a reason why bitmap is better than a drawable?

Comment: Its on need, upto my knowledge Drawable is something which can be drawn. 
Bitmap - is specific type of Drawable which is image, like: PNG, JPEG or so

Comment: I updated my code to include the Bitmap but it is not showing me the image, same result at drawable, could it be the sizing of the image on the phone messing it up?

Comment: Tried with one of the libraries in the link you provided and it works great thank you thank you!