# How to load image from web in ImageView(main activity) for an app?

Tags: android, android-studio

The *main activity* xml file with *ImageView* has *src*. How to link it to an online image(url).

PS: Just starting with Java and Android Studio, so i know it might be a silly question. 
Any help appreciated :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535924/how-to-get-image-from-url-website-in-imageview-in-android I think you may got your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picasso is the best approach to show image into imageview.
Use picasso library to display image from web in an ImageView.
Add dependency in your build.gradle like this :

```
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Now to display an image from web.Write this code to your activity.

```
 Picasso.with(mActivity)
                    .load(model.getUserPhotoURL())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.no_user)
                    .error(R.drawable.no_user)
                    .into(holder.imgUser);
```

Where,

> 1. load = Url of an image you want to display.
> 2. placeholder = Image/Drawable you want to show till your image loads.
> 3. error = Image/Drawable you want to show if your url image contains error.
> 4. into = Id of an imageview where you want to display image.

Note: Make sure you have given Internet permission.

Check this link for more detail : http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Thanks for accepting an answer.Have fun.!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Glide**  Or **Picaso** Libraries for that .

{ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

Glide.with(this).load("your link of image").into(imageView);}

above is example of glide.

here is the link for library

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 1):

Add a class

```
    public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;
public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = bmImage;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      //  Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}
 }
```

Then use

```
            new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute("url");
```